# How to reference a setInterval() id from itself in JavaScript, without help of an outer scope?

Tags: javascript

Just out of curiosity: can I reference a `setInterval()` id from itself, without having to store itself in a variable?

So, instead of doing this:

```
function counter() {
  console.log(id + ": " + count++);
  if (count > 10)
    clearInterval(id);
}

var count = 0;
var id = setInterval(counter, 250);
```

I'd be doing this:

```
function counter() {
  console.log(aReferenceToItsOwnId + ": " + count++);
  if (count > 10)
    clearInterval(aReferenceToItsOwnId);
}

var count = 0;
setInterval(counter, 250);
```

Which would, just in example, allow me to reuse the function simply, like this:

```
setInterval(counter, 200);
setInterval(counter, 250);
setInterval(counter, 333);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. The only place accessible to your code that the id is tracked is the return value of the `setInterval` function.

If you want to reuse the function, you could wrap it like:

```
function startCounter(time) {
    function counter() { ... }
    var count = 0;
    var id = setInterval(counter, time);
}

startCounter(200);
startCounter(250);
startCounter(333);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use additional parameter of function to do this.

```
var si1=setInterval(function(){counter(1);},200);
var si2=setInterval(function(){counter(2);},250);
var si3=setInterval(function(){counter(3);},333);

function counter(id)
{
    ...
    clearInterval(window['si'+id]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Don't use `window` properties. Just pass the `siX` variable directly as the parameter!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers state, it is impossible. However, you could create a helper function to greatly ease that fact.

### Code

```js
function timer(callback, interval) {
    var id = setInterval(function() {
        callback.call({ id: id });
    }, interval);
};
```

### Usage

```js
var count = 0;

function counter() {
    console.log(this.id + ' - ' + count++);

    if (count > 10) clearInterval(this.id);
};

timer(counter, 250);
timer(counter, 300);
```